# Issues with tfjs on iPhone/Safari (not behaving as expected)

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have trained a model that works OK predicting on Desktop browsers (Chrome & Safari on Mac) but it fails on Safari on IPhone (I get loads of NaN).

I have identified that a basic generation of a oneHot, has differences on both platforms:

For example

tf.oneHot([1],5)

creates:

[0,1,0,0,0] on my desktop browser (as expected)

[0,0,0,0,0] on iphone / Safari

I have created a demo page that shows this behaviour on https://beta.observablehq.com/@elaval/issue-with-tensorflowjs-on-iphone-safari

(please try it and tell me if you get [0,1,0,0,0] or [0,0,0,0,0] in different platforms - e.g. Android).

Any idea on what is the root cause for this?  Does this fails in all mobile phones  or is it only in Safari? How can we overcome the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I just got a reply to this question in the tensorflow.js Google group:

"This is a known issue and we are actively working to fix it asap."

Comment: you could have posted a link to the page